# Sixteenth note interval to beats per minute

Tags: c, math

I am writing a drum machine program. I need a function that takes the amount of microseconds between two sixteenth-notes as input, and outputs a beats-per-minute value. I would prefer the function to be in C.

I already have the drum machine working, but I would like a beats-per-minute representation so users can increase the value to increase tempo.

Comment: Um... divide the number of microseconds in a minute by your time interval, giving you the number of sixteenths per minute. Further divide that by 4 to get beats instead, and round to nearest. (Half a second of algebra then says that you can also just divide 15000000 by your input and round).

Comment: Thanks Henning! I was able to get it without actual C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Henning's answer is correct as to the mathematics. Here is an actual C function.

```
double GetBPMFromSixteenthDist(double nMsBetweenSixteenths)
{
   return 15000000  / nMsBetweenSixteenths;
}
```

Comment: That's not C, that looks more like C# or Java.

Comment: I don't see how Henning was rude. This is a basic algebra/units conversion question, not a programming question, and he still answered it anyway.